# Abnormal ionisation energy trend: Group 13 and 14

Tags: periodic-trends, periodic-table, ionization-energy

I was going through some ionisation energy data, where I came across the following:

*Ionisation energy order for Group 13 and 14*:

B > Al ≈ Ga > **In < Tl**

C > Si > Ge > **Sn < Pb**

What could be the possible reason for reversal in trend after fourth period? 
I'm not sure how accurately it can be attributed to screening effect.

An explanation would be great.

Comment: d-orbital contraction.

Comment: @Cyclohexanol. You meant the lanthanide contraction I guess?